# Need help editing multiple files using sed in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed, terminal

I am trying to do a simple operation here. Which is to cut a few characters from one file (style.css)  do a find a replace on another file   (client_custom.css) for more then 100 directories with different names

When I use the following command

```
for d in */; do sed -n 73p ~/assets/*/style.css | cut -c  29-35 | xargs -I :hex:  sed -i 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/' ~/assets/*/client_custom.css $d; done
```

It keeps giving me the following error for all the directories

```
sed: couldn't edit dirname/: not a regular file
```

I am confused on why its giving me that error message explicitly gave the full path to the file. It works perfectly fine without a `for loop`.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` doesn't support folders as input.

```
for d in */;
```

puts folders into `$d`. If you write `sed ... $d`, then BASH will put the folder name into the arguments of `sed` and the poor tool will be confused.

Also `~/assets/*/client_custom.css` since this will expand to all the files which match this pattern. So `sed` will be called once with all file names. You probably want to invoke `sed` once per file name.

Try

```
for f in ~/assets/*/client_custom.css; do
    ... | sed -i 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/' $f
done
```

or, even better:

```
for f in ~/assets/*/client_custom.css; do
    ... | sed 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/' "${f}.in" > "${f}"
done
```

(which doesn't overwrite the output file). This way, you can keep the "*.in" files, edit them with the patterns and then use `sed` to "expand" all the variables.